# Pine script - check to see how many active trades I'm in

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to limit the amount of trades my script can be in at any one time.
I can get in and out of positions, but I want to limit total to 5 so I dont have too much risk or draw down.
I use below to get in/out of trade.

```
strategy.entry(id = "Long", long = true, when = minLongMoveTrue, stop = percentMove)

strategy.entry(id = "Short", long = true, when = minShortMoveTrue, stop = percentMove)
```

`strategy.position_size` seems only look at total shares active, but cannot discern how many active trades I am in.

Maybe I need to set up a counter since pine script doesnt have inbuilt function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in variable `strategy.opentrades` to get the count of open trades.

> Number of market position entries, which were not closed and remain
> opened. If there is no open market position, 0 is returned.

You can also use `strategy.risk.max_drawdown` as risk management.

> The purpose of this rule is to determine maximum drawdown. The rule
> affects the whole strategy. Once the maximum drawdown value is
> reached, all pending orders are cancelled, all open positions are
> closed and no new orders can be placed.